# Use AND operator for email addresses in MS Outlook 2010 filtering rule

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, email-filter

I would to move email messages to a specific folder if them were sent to both of distribution lists I specify.

For example there are two or distribution lists: *Delivery and *Kitchen. I already have a rule for each or them. So mail sent to *Delivery get to "Devivery" folder and *Kitchen to "Kitchen" folder. Now I want to set up a rule to move messages sent to both *Delivery and *Kitchen to another folder "Delivery for Kitchen".

I was trying to select both lists in the email picker from Rules Wizard, but it suggests only "OR" operation for addresses, so it doesn't do the job. Is there any other way to set up the rule I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this natively, Outlook doesn't support this. But you can use a trick. For example, create a Kitchen rule that will check for *Kitchen DL and assign a Kitchen category to a message; don't set "stop processing more rules" check. Now create a Delivery rule that checks for *Delivery DL and also checks for Kitchen category; clear Kitchen category in this rule's actions, select move to "Delivery and Kitchen" folder and also set "stop processing more rules". Make sure the Delivery rule is right below Kitchen rule in the list of rules. That's all!